# Button Functionality not working after selecting loading a different fragment and then moving back

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm having a strange issue in a project I'm currently working on. I'm currently creating an enigma machine app on Android Studio, the project is not complete as most of my time has been trying to get the UI stuff to work.

When I press the letter q on the lower keyboard I want the upper keyboard's q to light up as well. This works properly when I launch the app for the first time, but when I move to a new fragment using the navigation bar, then move back to the Enigma Machine fragment, when I press the letter q, the upper keyboard does not light up.

I tried using Log to track if the onKeyboardClick method was still being ran, and the if statement inside. Both are functioning correctly, the only thing that does now work, is the letters colorFill does not change (after coming from a different fragment).

lampboardAL is an arraylist that contains all the letters in the upper image[image: Before pressing button]

[image: After pressing button]

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    int buttonID;
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_enigma, container, false);
    RelativeLayout keyButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.parent);

    for (int i = 0; i < keyButton.getChildCount(); i++) {
        //Log.i("OnKeyboardClick", String.valueOf(keyButton.getChildAt(i)));
        if(keyButton.getChildAt(i) instanceof AppCompatImageView && i <= 3) {
            ImageView rotorImage = (ImageView) keyButton.getChildAt(i);
            RotorAL.add(rotorImage);
        }
        if(keyButton.getChildAt(i) instanceof AppCompatImageView && i > 3){
            ImageView lampboard = (ImageView) keyButton.getChildAt(i);
            lampboardAL.add(lampboard);
        }else if(keyButton.getChildAt(i) instanceof AppCompatImageButton){
            ImageButton keyboard = (ImageButton) keyButton.getChildAt(i);
            keyboard.setOnClickListener(this::onKeyboardClick);
        }
    }
    blink = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.anim.blink);
    LampOnColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this.requireActivity(), R.color.electric_yellow);

    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        rotor1 = new Rotor(1,1);
        rotor2 = new Rotor(2,1);
        rotor3 = new Rotor(3,1);
        reflect = new Rotor(4,1);
    }else{
        String rotorState = savedInstanceState.getString(ROTOR_STATE);
        rotor1 = new Rotor(Character.getNumericValue(rotorState.charAt(0)),Character.getNumericValue(rotorState.charAt(1)));
        rotor2 = new Rotor(Character.getNumericValue(rotorState.charAt(2)),Character.getNumericValue(rotorState.charAt(3)));
        rotor3 = new Rotor(Character.getNumericValue(rotorState.charAt(4)),Character.getNumericValue(rotorState.charAt(5)));
        reflect = new Rotor(Character.getNumericValue(rotorState.charAt(6)),Character.getNumericValue(rotorState.charAt(7)));
    }


    return rootView;
```

```
private void onKeyboardClick(@NonNull View view){
    Log.i("OnKeyboardClick", String .valueOf(view.getId()));
    if(view.getId() == R.id.key_q){
        Log.i("AfterKeyboardClick", String.valueOf(lampboardAL.get(0)));
        lampboardAL.get(0).setColorFilter(LampOnColor);
    }

}
```

I'm not sure where to start when it comes to fixing this issue because both the onKeybardClick function triggers and the if statment, the only issue is that the setColorFilter does not work after you've loaded a different fragment then returned to the enigma machine fragment.